# PDO table inside table using json

Tags: php, json, pdo

I want to send 3 tables in my MySQL (PDO) using json

My tables:

```
$stmt1 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM data WHERE id='1'");
$stmt1->execute();
$result1 = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM weeks WHERE id='2'");
$stmt2->execute();
$result2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$stmt3 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='1'");
$stmt3->execute();
$result3 = $stmt3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Question how to send it to this **format**:

```
{"data":[{
                   "title":"name of module2",
                   "description":"description of module2",
                   "weeks":[{"id":2, "title":"Week 02"}],
                   "user":[{"id":2, "name":"john"}],
}]}
```

Comment: And you have tried **what**? to get this result

Comment: $response['data'] = $result; $response['data']['weeks'] = $result1; $response['data']['user'] = $result2; I tried in the form of but did not :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by returning objects from PDO as that is what you want.

Then only select from the table the columns that you actually need

Then build the data structure that you believe you want from the returned data

```
$stmt1 = $db->prepare("SELECT title,description FROM data WHERE id='1'");
$stmt1->execute();
$data = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT id,title FROM weeks WHERE id='2'");
$stmt2->execute();
$data->weeks[] = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$stmt3 = $db->prepare("SELECT id,name FROM user WHERE id='1'");
$stmt3->execute();
$data->user[] = $stmt3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$response = new stdClass();
$response->data[] = $data;

print_r($response);
echo json_encode($response);
```

RESULT:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => name of module2
                    [description] => description of module2
                    [weeks] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                    [title] => Week 02
                                )

                        )

                    [user] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                    [name] => john
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Giving a JSON String of

```
{"data":[{"title":"name of module2",
          "description":"description of module2",
          "weeks":[{"id":2,"title":"Week 02"}],
          "user":[{"id":2,"name":"john"}]
        }]
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'FETCH_OBJECT' in /test.php on line 11 :(

Comment: Sorry, TYPO fixed should have been `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`

Comment: If the only first one is (data) to make an array.  I want to data fetchAll $data = $stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); bu not working

Comment: forexample:
{"data":[{"title":"name of module2",
          "description":"description of module2",
          "weeks":[{"id":2,"title":"Week 02"}],
          "user":[{"id":2,"name":"john"}]
        },{"title":"name of module2",
          "description":"description of module2",
          "weeks":[{"id":2,"title":"Week 02"}],
          "user":[{"id":2,"name":"john"}]
        }]
}

Comment: Your example code was selecting a single specific row i.e.`WHERE id='1'` that is why I answered the question the way I did.

Comment: You will have to ask another question, and supply queries that match you actual requirements

Comment: I needed this example too. This example is very useful. But I need the example of the second responsibility.

Comment: New question link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42641706/json-table-inside-table