# Json table inside table

Tags: php, json, pdo

I want to send 3 tables in my MySQL (PDO) using json. There is a loop in the first table
Note: 
First table (fetchAll) 
Second table (fetch)
Third table (fetch)

```html
$stmt1 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM data WHERE countid='1'");
$stmt1->execute();
$data = $stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT id,title FROM weeks WHERE id='2'");
$stmt2->execute();
$data->weeks[] = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$stmt3 = $db->prepare("SELECT id,name FROM user WHERE id='1'");
$stmt3->execute();
$data->user[] = $stmt3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$response = new stdClass();
$response->data[] = $data;

echo json_encode($response);
```

how to send it to this format:

```html
{"data":[
        {"title":"name of module1",
          "description":"description of module1",
          "weeks":[{"id":1,"title":"Week 01"}],
          "user":[{"id":1,"name":"george"}]
        },
        {"title":"name of module2",
          "description":"description of module2",
          "weeks":[{"id":2,"title":"Week 02"}],
          "user":[{"id":2,"name":"john"}]
        }
        ]
}
```

**data:** id, name, content, user_id, week, countid;

**weeks:** id, data_id, checkin, checkout;

**user:** id, username, name, surname;

(**data.id==weeks.data_id**) and (**data.user_id==user.id**) same ..

Comment: In the first question, the first table was not an array. All of the codes need to be changed in order to make it an array, so I ask a new question. The questioner answered that he could answer him in a separate question.

Comment: There does not seem to be a need for a `fetchAll` as you are only selecting one row in the first query

Comment: SELECT * FROM my first query

Comment: But `WHERE countid='1'` or is there more than 1 row with `countid=1`

Comment: Also what column in the `data` table links it to the `weeks` and `user` tables

Comment: A look at the schema would be useful

Comment: data : id, name, content, user_id, week ;
weeks: id, data_id, checkin, checkout;
user: id, username, name, surname;

(data.id==weeks.data_id) and (data.user_id==user.id) same

Comment: If you write me a sample structure with one common column, I can edit it by myself

Comment: I dont see `countid` anywhere in that list of columns

Comment: sorry I added now.

Comment: I added it to the bottom of the question

Comment: I assume `title` and `description` also exist in the `data` table?

Comment: Yes there are other brass columns but i did not write to make confusion..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745588/multiple-mysql-table-to-json-encode?answertab=active#tab-top Might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so a little more code is required now. You have to get all the `data` rows and then use the keys in there to get the related rows from the other 2 tables.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM data WHERE countid='1'");
$stmt->execute();
$datas = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach ( $datas as $key => &$data ) {
    // get related weeks data
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id,title FROM weeks WHERE data_id=:id ORDER BY id");
    $stmt->execute( array(':id'=>$data->id) );
    $data->weeks = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    // get related user data  
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id,name FROM user WHERE id=:id ORDER BY id");
    $stmt->execute( array(':id'=>$data->user_id) );
    $data->user = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

echo json_encode( array('data'=>$datas) );
```

Results:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "name of module1",
            "description": "description of module 1",
            "user_id": 1,
            "week": "1",
            "countid": 1,
            "weeks": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "title": "Week 01"
                }
            ],
            "user": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "chris"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "name of module 2",
            "description": "description of module 2",
            "user_id": 2,
            "week": "2",
            "countid": 1,
            "weeks": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "title": "Week 02"
                }
            ],
            "user": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "john"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/villabul/domains/yazlikvillabul.com/public_html/uyelik/test.php on line 17
LINE 17: $data[$key]->weeks[] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

Comment: Amended try that

Comment: same Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/villabul/domains/yazlikvillabul.com/public_html/uyelik‌​/test.php on line 17